# Creating a file and a folder in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to create a file in a user folder and populate it with some basic text. seems simple, but i keep getting an error:

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\websites\admin\upload\users\testuserID\testuserIDSampleRecord.txt'."} System.Exception {System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException}

my website is located under: `c:\websites\testsite\`, so the full path should be:

```
c:/websites/testsite/admin/upload/users/
```

the IIS localhost is set to point to `c:/websites/` so when i run it i type `localhost/testsite` to get to it

here is what i have:

```
 try
            {
           string SampleCaseText =  BuildTextRecord();
           string username = (string)Session["userid"];
           string folderPath = "/testsite/admin/upload/users/" + username;
           bool IsExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(folderPath));

            if(!IsExists)
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(folderPath));

            System.IO.File.Create(folderPath + "/" + username + "SampleRecord.txt");


            File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(folderPath, username + "SampleRecord.txt"), SampleCaseText);


            }
```

it created the new folder testuserID in the correct place, but it fails when trying to create/write the file.

Comment: Trying using the `System.Path.CombinePath` function, instead of string concatenation.  Also, I think the call to `System.IO.File.Create` should be using the Windows ` \ `  instead of the web `/`

Comment: what the error you getting ?

Comment: What about access rights? Can you check if folder is created going into directory through windows explorer?

Comment: I believe the root `C:` is similar to `Program Files` it requires Elevated Permissions. Try changing the directory to local `My Documents` or `App Data` and if the error vanishes then it is permissions.

Comment: @Greg you are correct when it comes to writing a file to those locations. However if you create a folder first, then you can write to that folder without issue (with the correct writes of course)

Comment: @SimonHalsey The way it sounded to me, is it wasn't creating the folder though.

Comment: @Greg could be permissions, but since the parent folder isn't root, then it wouldn't be blocked.

Comment: @SimonHalsey Makes sense, I just know `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\` which is the IIS Folder for example requires permission otherwise you can't write a folder or file to it because it is based off the root.

Comment: @Greg that's for slightly different reasons. Good security practice says your web root shouldn't be writeable, as that makes it easier for someone to exploit your site. any folders you write to by your website should be out of the web root & therefore not browsable & much harder to exploit. Protected root & programs folder is just standard system protection for windows

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of errors that I see off hand that **could** be causing trouble...

Firstly instead of using the web `/` folder delimiter, use the windows `\` one instead.

Secondly, you're not using `Server.MapPath` in all the location you should be... resulting in using the web relative path instead of the local windows path.

Try something like this, where I've convert the folder to a windows path at the start, and put the converted `userFilename` into it's own variable, and used that instead...

```
string folderPath = Server.MapPath("/testsite/admin/upload/users/" + username);
bool IsExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(folderPath);
if(!IsExists)
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);

string userFilename = Path.Combine(folderPath, username + "SampleRecord.txt");
System.IO.File.Create(userFilename);
File.WriteAllText(userFilename, SampleCaseText);
```

Comment: thanks! alsmot there. now i'm getting: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\websites\testwebsite\admin\upload\users\testUser\testUserSampleRecord.txt' because it is being used by another process.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that may help - to make it a bit easier I did not include code that creates a file or a folder, but simply to grab an existing file, open it and write to it.

Hopefully this gives some direction and you can go from there.

```
private void Error(string error)
    {
        var dir= new DirectoryInfo(@"yourpathhere");
        var fi = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(dir.FullName, "errors.txt"));

        using (FileStream fs = fi.OpenWrite())
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
            sw.Write(error);
            sw.Close();
            sw.Dispose();
        }

    }
```

One thing to note: make sure you have permissions on the folder and file you wish to write to.